Poor performance when working with DMatrix in nalgebra
I'm trying to write a basic neural network in Rust using nalgebra, and it is very very slow; even slower than the Python version. Training the network on 60000 28x28 pixel images takes over 10 minutes for example. I suspect it is because I keep cloning really large vectors/data but I'm not sure how to pass by reference because DMatrix doesn't implement copy (and using SMatrix causes stack overflow).
For instance, this is my train function:
 pub fn train(&mut self, input_nodes: Vec<f64>, target_nodes: Vec<f64>) -> () {
        let input: DMatrix<f64> = DMatrix::from_vec(784, 1, input_nodes);
        let target: DMatrix<f64> = DMatrix::from_vec(10, 1, target_nodes);

        let hidden_inputs: DMatrix<f64> = self.weights_input_hidden.clone() * input.clone();
        let hidden_outputs: DMatrix<f64> = hidden_inputs.map(|x| self.sigmoid(x));

        let final_inputs: DMatrix<f64> =
            self.weights_hidden_output.clone() * hidden_outputs.clone();
        let final_outputs: DMatrix<f64> = final_inputs.map(|x| self.sigmoid(x));

        let output_errors: DMatrix<f64> = target - final_outputs.clone();
        let hidden_errors: DMatrix<f64> =
            self.weights_hidden_output.transpose() * output_errors.clone();

        self.weights_hidden_output += self.learning_rate
            * ((output_errors
                .component_mul(&final_outputs)
                .component_mul(&(DMatrix::repeat(10, 1, 1.0) - final_outputs)))
                * hidden_outputs.transpose());
        self.weights_input_hidden += self.learning_rate
            * ((hidden_errors
                .component_mul(&hidden_outputs)
                .component_mul(&(DMatrix::repeat(200, 1, 1.0) - hidden_outputs)))
                * input.transpose());
    }

You can see that there are a lot of instances where I have to .clone() large matrices. I've t ried using Rc/RefCell and Arc, but at the end of the day, to access the matrix itself when doing computation, I'm forced to clone it anyway. So what are ways I can improve the efficiency of my code? I just learned rust so I'm still learning the borrow checker.

Please provide a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Note that you can do math operations with references.

You haven't shown us the "Python version", but note that it probably does all the computations in highly optimized C/C++/Assembly (at least if it's using any of the usual suspects, numpy, PyTorch and so on). Rust won't be any faster on these operations, so the only improvement you can expect is the cost of the Python interface, which should be negligible.

Right, I guess that makes sense. I suppose my question really boils down to: is there a way to write my train function without having to clone my DMatrixs multiple times? I've tried doing references, but the "*" operator wants me to deref the matrix, but DMatrix doesn't implement copy.
